# Internal Server error 500 on mysql query using doctrine with symfony 3

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.4

I had try execute a sql query in raw, with the next code:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
$sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE client"; 
$stmt = $this->entityManager->getConnection()->prepare($sql)->execute();
```

And always get error 500, if change the truncate for an insert, or select get 500 to.

This error only appears with use SQL raw, when I use DQL, run correctly.

Any idea?

This code is hosted in Bluemix, and I checked the cloud foundry configuration, and it is equal that other projects that run ok

Comment: What exactly error do you have? Find it in server logs or enable errors output in that page via ini_set('display_errors', '1');.

Comment: I used error_reporting(E_ALL);        ini_set('display_errors', 1);, but not showed nothing

Comment: not show nothing again

Comment: add ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1)

Comment: not show nothing again only the error 500

Comment: then copy to local web server and try to find error in logs or via enable error output in php.ini

Comment: @eslop Are you sure that `$this->entityManager` should not be replaced with `$em`?

Answer (score 0):

Use your $em var instead of entityManager in your query

Answer (score 0):

In my case following code is working.

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $connection = $em->getConnection();
    $platform = $connection->getDatabasePlatform();

    $truncateSql = $platform->getTruncateTableSQL('table_name');
    $connection->executeUpdate($truncateSql);

    $em->flush();
```

Comment: This run work, but the problem, is that I can´t execute mysql raw, and I need too execute a "load data infile" query